# Comparing column value with n rows value in row slice

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming a dataframe:

```
>>> data = pd.DataFrame([[9],[5],[1],[2]])
>>> data
   0
0  9
1  5
2  1
3  2
```

Say I want to add a column that will compare the previous 2 or n rows and if any of those numbers are higher than the current number, write False, else True meaning no numbers in the previous 2 or n rows are higher than number at the current row.

Example:

```
   0  Highest
0  9   True
1  5   True
2  1   False
3  2   NaN
```

9 is higher than 5 and 1, 5 is higher than 1 and 2, but 1 is not higher than 2 etc etc.
I need to do this with n rows, from 20 to 50+

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `pandas.Series.rolling.max`:

```
s = data[0]
data["Highest"] = s.eq(s[::-1].rolling(2).max())
print(data)
```

Output:

```
   0  Highest
0  9     True
1  5     True
2  1    False
3  2    False
```

Insight:

- `s[::-1]`: given the OP's condition, the max comparison is done on next *n* items. IMO, this is same as comparing the series in a reversed manner.
- `pd.Series.rolling`: provides `n` rolling windows calculation. In other words, creates mini batches for local comparison. It then uses `max` as per the OP
- `pd.Series.eq`: provides element-wise comparison of `self` and `input`, so to have a boolean array whether the given element (or row) is highest.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, when using on different columns I have to change eq to gt as eq will not give the right answer.

Comment: @merit_2 I've added some explanation :)